# I am trying to find PDF documentation for Maplex for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-9.3, labeling

Does anyone know where to find the PDF documentation for Maplex for ArcGIS 9.3 ? There was a website from ESRI but it was broken link ?

I need to review it because I am working on impaired streams and lakes and needs their labels to set it up properly. Trying to do it in Label Manager several times.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a whitepaper - [White Paper on Maplex](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/maplex-for-arcgis.pdf)

Here is the help doc - [Using Maplex for ArcGIS](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Maplex_for_ArcGIS_Tutorial.pdf)

Those are the standard docs you will find...

Comment: for ArcGIS10 users use http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/maplex-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Maplex 9.3 Help Topic](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_Maplex)

[Maplex 10 Help Topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003s00000071000000.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You might also look through the ESRI Mapping Center "Ask a Cartographer" archives under the Maplex category.  http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.gateway